# Regrid numpy array based on cell area

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import block_reduce

arr = np.random.random((6, 6))
area_cell = np.random.random((6, 6))

block_reduce(arr, block_size=(2, 2), func=np.ma.mean)
```

I would like to regrid a numpy array `arr` from 6 x 6 size to 3 x 3. Using the skimage function block_reduce for this.

However, `block_reduce` assumes each grid cell has same size. How can I solve this problem, when each grid cell has a different size? In this case size of each grid cell is given by the numpy array `area_cell`

-- EDIT:

An example:

`arr`

```
0.25    0.58    0.69    0.74
0.49    0.11    0.10    0.41
0.43    0.76    0.65    0.79
0.72    0.97    0.92    0.09
```

If all elements of `area_cell` were 1, and we were to convert 4 x 4 arr into 2 x 2, result would be:

```
0.36    0.48
0.72    0.61
```

However, if `area_cell` is as follows:

```
0.00    1.00    1.00    0.00
0.00    1.00    0.00    0.50
0.20    1.00    0.80    0.80
0.00    0.00    1.00    1.00
```

Then, result becomes:

```
0.17    0.22
0.21    0.54
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Do you mean to say that `block_size` must all have the same scaling factors?  They can be arbitrary positive integers.

Comment: @rayryeng, I want to do weighted average rather than simple mean. The weights are defined in `area_cell`. The `block_size` is not relevant in this case. In my particular use case, `block_size` always has same scaling factors.

Comment: Use some numeric values as input elements and show us the expected o/p?

Comment: @Divakar, added an example to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are still reducing by blocks, but after scaling `arr` with `area_cell`. So, you just need to perform element-wise multiplication between these two arrays and use the same `block_reduce` code on that product array, like so -

```
block_reduce(arr*area_cell, block_size=(2, 2), func=np.ma.mean)
```

Alternatively, we can simply use [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) after reshaping to a `4D` version of the product array, like so -

```
m,n = arr.shape
out = (arr*area_cell).reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).mean(axis=(1,3))
```

Sample run -

```
In [21]: arr
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0.25,  0.58,  0.69,  0.74],
       [ 0.49,  0.11,  0.1 ,  0.41],
       [ 0.43,  0.76,  0.65,  0.79],
       [ 0.72,  0.97,  0.92,  0.09]])

In [22]: area_cell
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 0.2,  1. ,  0.8,  0.8],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  1. ]])

In [23]: block_reduce(arr*area_cell, block_size=(2, 2), func=np.ma.mean)
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0.1725 ,  0.22375],
       [ 0.2115 ,  0.5405 ]])

In [24]: m,n = arr.shape

In [25]: (arr*area_cell).reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).mean(axis=(1,3))
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0.1725 ,  0.22375],
       [ 0.2115 ,  0.5405 ]])
```